# Set RSA Parameters

Tags: c#, rsa

I have been provided with M, Exponent and D components of and RSA parameter and have been trying to encrypt data using it in C#.NET. I was wondering as parts of public key which of these components are necessary to have to encrypt data? Also, the exponent is 10001 in base 16. What should I set the RsaParameters.Exponent parameter in C#? I don't know how exactly I should interpret that number and place it in Exponent which is a byte array. Don't the components need to have an even length in base 16?

Thanks.

Comment: I don't know what your M is. You need n and e to encrypt messages. They make up the public key. n is the product of two big prime numbers and e is the exponent. Your d is part of the private key. You need it to decrypt data. Please provide more information about what M actually is.

Comment: I think Hamid means "N", the Modulus.

Answer (score 5):

```
RSAParameters rsaKeyInfo = new RSAParameters
{
   Exponent = new byte[] {1, 0, 1},
   ...
};

using (RSACryptoServiceProvider rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider())
{
    rsa.ImportParameters(rsaKeyInfo);
    rsa.Decrypt(...)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a [sample of code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.security.cryptography.rsacryptoserviceprovider.encrypt.aspx)
So, you should set the Exponent as byte representation of number 65537 (10001 in base 16).
I'm not quite sure how it works in `RSACryptoServiceProvider`, but if you're using OpenSSL, the `BitConverter.GetBytes(65537)` is a bad idea, cause it's `{1, 0, 1, 0}`, but not `{1, 0, 1}` and it doesn't work correctly. So, I think it's better to leave it in a way it wrote in MSDN's example:

```
byte[] Exponent = {1,0,1};
```